# Xcode 8.1 storyboard showing blue lines only

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode8

I installed Xcode 8.1 and the storyboard shows only blue lines, for all UI elements. If someone has figured it out let me know. I am unable to revert it to even Xcode 8.0.

Comment: Got the same problem

Comment: Check Editor->Canvas->Show Layout Rectangles is Unchecked in Xcode Menu. try that it may work.

Comment: Note: saw this in Xcode 10.3 as well.

Answer (score 21):

Don't worry revert back to old xcode

To remove the blue lines,

First, select a view controller in the storyboard.

Then, go to *Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles*

This will hide the blue lines.

You may have to repeat this 2 or 3 times to make it work.

[image: Image Link]

Answer (score 13):

Ok, So finally I too got the blue line problem in **Xcode 8.1**

Here is the screenshot

[image: Xcode screenshot of interface builder issue]

We can see the error message:

> An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited

with a **Report a Bug** button on the right side.

Don't know why it happened. But I just quit Xcode and Simulator and restarted it. That fixed it and I got the UI elements back.

Comment: Have reported 4,5 times

Comment: force quit both xcode and simulator. And then open project with xcode again

Comment: Same issue for Xcode 9.0.1 got resolved by restarting Xcode only.

Comment: Same happened with in Xcode 9.2 when I converted my Swift 3 code to Swift 4. With same error msg. Restarting did worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the blue rectangles is actually a feature of Xcode editor.
You can turn this On/Off by going to 
Editor menu->Canvas->Show Bounds Rectangles

But yes, seeing just the blue boxes seems to be a bug. Usually happens if you have been switching between various versions of Xcode frequently. I guess quitting and reopening Xcode shall resolve this temporary issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when I had upgraded to Mojave and then installed an older Xcode (10.1) version. To fix I deleted all Xcode (10.2/10.1) versions and then installed Xcode 10 and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Colleague had similar problem with Xcode 10.3 / 10.2, deleting the latter fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me on several occasions. For me it almost always occurred after dragging a `UILabel` from a `UITableViewCell` into a different view.

I was able to fix the problem by deleting the view controller in the storyboard that I did the dragging to/from, closing the app, and reopening the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in XCode 11, in my case even the view controllers was completely black. The problem was a Custom Class assigned to an UIButton. After a while i deleted the class because i didn't need it anymore, but the Button still had the class assigned.

Open the particular storyboard file, delete the assignment in Identity Inspector, restart Xcode. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue (only blue lines without details rendering) when upgrading Xcode without restarting the Mac. Killing the simulator fixed it:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```