# Xcode 10 storyboard not showing elements, only blue border

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, macos-mojave

[image]

After I upgrade to Mojave and update to Xcode 10 my storyboards are not showing any element, just displaying a blue border.

How can I fix this!

EDIT:
The answers given here [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301394/xcode-8-1-storyboard-showing-blue-lines-only) do not resolve my problem.

Comment: Did you try to delete derived data?

Comment: Yes, I already did that but didn't work, any other suggestion?

Comment: I know this may sounds silly but try to make a clean install of Xcode. Xcode 10 is buggy and the most unstable release of all times :/

Comment: I don't think so Xcode 10 has this kind of issue. This issue came in Xcode 9.3 also.

Answer (score 4):

Try these solutions:

1. Try to quit Xcode, then clear derived data first then open the Xcode project.
2. I attached a screenshot, make sure "Automatically Refresh Views" should be checked. Also, click on 'Refresh All Views' option.

Note: Try to enable and disable again to this property: 'Show Bound Rectangles'

[image]

Comment: I did as @iDev750 described, but without luck, and the Refresh All Views button stays disabled and I don't know how to enable it.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: I end up uninstalling and installing Xcode again, that solve the problem!

Comment: Ok, hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Yeah! it was the only solution. Is working know

Comment: Deleting derived data worked for me (and also clearing up more room on my device)